# Regex - Remove space behind & before string

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a json regex expression that removes the space behind ** and before ** for a markdown document:
Example:

```
This is the text that is in the source document ** text should be in bold ** more text
```

Result should be:

```
This is the text that is in the source document **text should be in bold** more text
```

My attempt:

```
[ ].[**][ ]
```

[Matches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVznt.png)

replace with

```
**
```

This results in :

```
This is the text that is in the source document**text should be in bold**more text
```

So not perfect, can anyone help me finetuning this expression?

Comment: I added my attempt

Comment: Are you aware of what `[ ].[**][ ]` matches? Check at regex101.com. Also, what is your programming language? Regex only matches texts, programming functions/methods replace strings. How are you using the pattern?

Comment: Added matches and json format

Comment: Yes, but what rules are you trying to implement? Remove spaces after odd double `*` and before even double `*`? Try `(?<!\S)\*{2}\s*(.*?)\s*\*{2}(?!\S)` and replace with `**$1**`, see https://regex101.com/r/UGho4M/1

Comment: Why is this tagged `json`? Removed. Please tag appropriately.

Comment: How about `\*\*\s+` ?

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to Wiktor:
`(?<!\S)\*{2}\s*(.*?)\s*\*{2}(?!\S)` and replace with `**$1**`